# How to link an array from another worksheet in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to use a formula to get values from one table column from another worksheet. I want to place the values in a single cell. I had tried using these formulas but it won't work:

```
=IF(worksheet2!A2:A4="Male",B2:B4,"")
=IF(worksheet2!A2:worksheet2!A4="Male",B2:B4,"")
=IF(worksheet2!A2:worksheet2!A4="Male",worksheet2!B2:worksheet2!B4,"")
```

Basically what I want to happen is: If any of the cells from column A of Worksheet2 contain the string "Male", then display their respective column B. Else, display none.

Is it possible to display in a single cell an array from another worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

This will return "Male" if "Male" is in your worksheet 2 range.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(worksheet2!A2:A4,"male")>=1,"Male","")
```

This will run a logical test to see if the count of "male" within A2:A4 is equal to or more than 1, if TRUE "Male" will be displayed, if FALSE nothing will.

However this is what I think you want to do:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(worksheet2!A2,"male")>=1,"male,"")
```

Only slightly different, but if you put this in B2 on your other worksheet it will show "Male" only if worksheet2!A2 contains "Male", rather than showing "Male" if any cell between A2 and A4 contained "Male".

You can drag this formula down to as far as your worksheet2! data goes.

I'm not sure i'm clear on what you'd like to do though, are you able to post an image or an example of what you are working with?